# Adding Page Numbers

Tags: c#, itext, itext7

I haven't really written anything outside of Powershell in a long time, and I know this is ugly, but I can't seem to figure out why my new PDF is not adding the page numbers. I pulled the example from [this itext kb.](https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/examples/adding-page-numbers-to-an-existing-pdf)

I tried to make this basic app so people in the office could add the page numbers to PDF's. Here's what I have so far. It will create the new PDF (duplicate of the original), but it's not adding the page numbers.

Basically they use button1 to find their PDF via the Windows File Explorer dialog. It just stores the filename in a textbox. The second button is the "save" and should take the src file and make a copy of the src with only adding the page number at the bottom of the file (or anywhere at this point).

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using iText.Kernel.Pdf;
using iText.Layout;
using iText.Layout.Element;
using iText.Layout.Properties;

namespace PDFManipulation
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int size = -1;
            DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog(); // Show the dialog.
            if (result == DialogResult.OK) // Test result.
            {
                string file = openFileDialog1.FileName;
                try
                {
                    string text = File.ReadAllText(file);
                    size = text.Length;
                    textBox1.Text = file;
                }
                catch (System.IO.IOException)
                {
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(size); // <-- Shows file size in debugging mode.
            Console.WriteLine(result); // <-- For debugging use.
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Stream myStream;
            //SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();

            if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                if ((myStream = saveFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
                {
                    // Code to write the stream goes here.
                    myStream.Close();
                    string SRC = textBox1.Text;
                    string DEST = saveFileDialog1.FileName;
                    FileInfo file = new FileInfo(DEST);
                    file.Directory.Create();
                    PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(SRC), new PdfWriter(DEST));
                    Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc);

                    int numberOfPages = pdfDoc.GetNumberOfPages();
                    for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfPages; i++)
                    {
                        // Write aligned text to the specified by parameters point
                        doc.ShowTextAligned(new Paragraph("page " + i + " of " + numberOfPages),559, 806, i, TextAlignment.CENTER, VerticalAlignment.TOP, 0);
                    }

                    doc.Close();
                }
            }
            MessageBox.Show("PDF Page Numbering Added!", "Pages Added",MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a dumb dumb. The x,y coordinates were off as the value 812 for the height is off the page.

Comment: As a hint, you should retrieve the crop box of the respective page and calculate coordinates relatively to the borders of that box if you want your code to work in generic contexts.